# Do the different mint lengths in the Token-2022 Program affect the dataSize of token accounts?

Tags: token-2022, token-account

The Token Program produces token accounts that are 165 bytes in length. This makes it easy to consistently filter for them when using getParsedProgramAccounts. But if we are creating token mints with various extensions using the Token-2022 Program, does that change the dataSize for token accounts to something other than 165? How would that impact our ability to fetch them in this manner?

For reference:

- https://spl.solana.com/token#finding-all-token-accounts-for-a-specific-mint
- https://spl.solana.com/token#finding-all-token-accounts-for-a-wallet
- https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#example-initializing-a-mint-with-mint-close-authority

That last item in the reference shows how to create the proper mint length for that extension, and there are other extensions, which makes them different from the standard MINT_SIZE of 82. How does that impact the dataSize of token accounts? Are they no longer consistently 165 bytes when using these extensions?

Comment: Mint extensions _only_ affect the size of the mint account, not the token accounts. Only token account extensions affect the size of token accounts. Keep in mind, some mint extensions may also require token account extensions to work properly, but there are many mint extensions that do not require token account extensions.